# How can I make an arrow on an instruction box on the right move to point to the field on the left that is in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a web page with a form on it.  The page is separated into two columns, left and right.  The form is on the left and there is a box with instructions on the right.

Currently, the box on the right is comprised of a [cssarrowplease](http://cssarrowplease.com/) #arrow_box div that is configured with the arrow pointing left.

I would like that arrow to move so that it points to the form field on the left that has focus.

By playing with the CSS, I can manually move the arrow up and down. However, I am unsure how to make those moves dynamically as I tab or click to focus on each different form field.

Comment: post some code. or create jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/  for your task ..

Comment: You can set position of form to absolute or relative, and then set top and left attributes of box to correspond values of input field `on('focusin')` and hide box `on('blur')`

Comment: @Victor your idea sounds similar to the answer that Phillip-juan posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I understand correctly, you can add classes for each position and change the class of the `#arrow_box div` according to the style when focus is on certain form fields.*

Although this is a lengthy method.

**CSS Class 1:**

```
.arrow_box 
{ 
    position: relative; 
    background: #88b7d5; 
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5; 
} 
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before 
{ 
    left: 100%; 
    border: solid transparent; 
    content: " "; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    pointer-events: none; 
} 
.arrow_box:after 
{ 
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); 
    border-left-color: #88b7d5; 
    border-width: 10px; 
    top: 10%; 
    margin-top: -10px; 
} 
.arrow_box:before 
{ 
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); 
    border-left-color: #c2e1f5; 
    border-width: 16px; 
    top: 10%; 
    margin-top: -16px; 
}
```

**and CSS Class 2:**

*The only change will be the className and the following:*
Example:

```
.arrow_box
{
    top: 10%;
}
```

*becomes*

```
.arrow_box_element2
{
    top: 20%;
}
```

Lets say you have a `JavaScript` method which is called when `Focus` is on *element*:

```
function onFocusElement1()
{
     $("#arrow_box").attr('class', 'arrow_box');
}

function onFocusElement2()
{
     $("#arrow_box").attr('class', 'arrow_box_element2');
}
```

*Hope this helps :)*

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are suggesting that I have a different CSS class that relates to each form field and that I switch to those classes as those fields come into focus. That could work. And I could probably convince jQuery to animate between each class as well. I will give this a try. Thanks.